# Correct type of apostrophe to use in HTML

Tags: html, character-encoding, apostrophe

If I write a paragraph using my keyboard straight into a text editor for a HTML document and one of the words has an apostrophe then the apostrophe will be written exactly like this:

`Here's an example of some text.`

However if copying from Word, the same sentence would appear as:

`Hereʼs an example of some text.`

What's the correct way to show them in a HTML document? As I normally do a find and replace to make them the same as `'`.

Additionally I can also write them using encoding:

```
&#700; = ʼ

&pos; = '

&#39; = '
```

Is there a standard way of doing this? I understand that `&pos;` is a HTML5 thing so `&#39;` might be the safer option but do you need to escape them? And which apostrophe should be used?

Answer (score 2):

> do you need to escape them?

The `'` character needs to be represented by an entity **only** if it appears in an attribute value delimited by `'` characters.

The `ʼ` character needs to be represented by an entity **only** if the document is encoded using a character encoding which does not include it. You should not be using such a character encoding this century (because Unicode support is ubiquitous).

> And which apostrophe should be used?

That's a typography question (not apropriate for Stackoverflow) and largely a matter of opinion.

Comment: It would be pointless, more bytes than needed, more work to type and (arguably) harder to read in the source code.

Comment: This answer would be improved with references to the HTML spec.